# C++ algorithm using reference or new value

Tags: c++, reference, copy-constructor, functor, unary-operator

I have a question about using functor return value and parameter. Lets have this code:

```
int op_increase (int i) { return ++i; }

int main () {
  std::vector<int> foo;
  std::vector<int> bar;

  // set some values:
  for (int i=1; i<6; i++)
    foo.push_back (i*10);                         // foo: 10 20 30 40 50

  bar.resize(foo.size());                         // allocate space

  std::transform (foo.begin(), foo.end(), bar.begin(), op_increase);
```

Now, functor accepts value (caling copy constructor) and when returning value it calls copy constructor again. I am curious if something is wrong when using these forms of functor which are fastest by my opinion

```
int& op_increase(int& i) {return ++i;}
```

or just

```
void op_increase(int& i) {++i;}
```

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Are you getting a compile error?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a matter of what is the best for you (anyway, the ones you are proposing are wrong), it is a matter of what is right from the point of view of `std::transform`.
See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) for the documentation.

It states that when you use an unary operator, its sign must be equivalent to the following:

```
Ret fun(const Type &a);
```

Moreover:

> The signature does not need to have const &.
>   The type Type must be such that an object of typeInputIt can be dereferenced and then implicitly converted to Type.
>   The type Ret must be such that an object of type OutputIt can be dereferenced and assigned a value of type Ret.

That said, it seems that you misunderstood what `transform` is meant for, that is:

> std::transform applies the given function to a range and stores the result in another range

According with your example, either you misunderstood it or it is not not what you want, so maybe `transform` is not what you are looking for.